# extjs/c# - how to save data from a form to a database?

Tags: c#, extjs, submit, extjs4

im trying to add a new user to my database via a form
i prepared the form but my problem is how to save the data from this form to my database ?
im using c# and extjs4.0.1

i know i need to use submit on a button and give it an url
i did that but when i click on it nothing happens! no errors! i get the success info box! but when i check the database, there is nothing inserted!like my updateuser function have never been called?!!

here is my form script:

```
buttons: [{
                     text: 'Save user',
                     handler: function () {
                             if (this.up('form').getForm().isValid())
                                 this.up('form').getForm().submit
                                 ({// this would submit the form to the configured url
                                     url: 'update.ashx',
                                     success: function (form, action) {
                                         Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                             title: 'Success !',
                                             msg: 'Changes saved successfully<br />',
                                             icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                                         })
                                     },                                        
                                 });
                                 this.up('form').getForm().reset();

                     }
```

and here is my update.ashx script:

```
public class update : IHttpHandler
{
    SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection("....");

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {        }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get           {          return false;            }
    }

    public void updateUser(string firstname, string lastname, string email)
    {


        string str = "insert into User  (Name , FName , Email ) values ( '" + firstname + "' , '" + lastname + "' , '" + email + "' )";

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(str);
        sqlCommand.Connection = dbConn;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        dbConn.Open();

        if (sqlCommand.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbConn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

do you have any idea please?
at least let me know if im on the right way or not...
thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all "success: function (form, action)" this function call doesn't mean that the update user was a succes , just that the submit was successful .. for success you need to encode a json with success true, and then action.result.success will determine if success was true... check the api .....

Second, i'm not much of a c# guy ... but it seems you don't even process the request

**Edit:**

To avoid your duplicate problem send an extra param to the handler ... and execute the update method only when receiving the update action in the request

```
url: 'update.ashx',
params: {action: 'update'},
success: function (form, action) {
```

the form submit sends the form values to the handler inside the HttpRequest object contained by the context object.. for retriving the form values you can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx example

Comment: thank you,im just begining in c# , what make u say i dont process the request?

Comment: well ProcessRequest is the method called from the ajax request .. so you have to get the params sent form the request (they should be in context.HttpRequest.params ... or something like that) So you have to select the firstname, lastname, email from the context object and then call the method updateUser(firstname,lastname,email)

Comment: i am trying what u said, the problem is that the Processrequest seem to be executed at the start of the project before i actually call it, so iget data iserted twice!

Comment: and the main problem is that i dont know how to send my form feilds values to my handler?!

Comment: thank you, now i managed to read the extra param like this `context.Request.Params["action"] ` and the duplicate issue is gone :) thanks again. But i still dont know how to retreive the other params sent with submit (the form feilds values )

Comment: i tried to use the same with the id of the fields but it didnt work, yet it worked with the dataindex name..is that normal? does the submit send the params with the store ids?

Comment: The submit sends the parameters the same way the action parameter is sent, use the 'name' config in extjs fields to specify ewach field the parameter name. So if you have a textfield in the form  and you set name: 'someParam', you will get in the request context.Request.Params["someParam"] = value of the textfield